# Print out all files in current directory and subdirectories in Python

Tags: python, file

Suppose I have the path directory `pathname`. I can print all the files in that directory by doing

```
glob.glob('*')
```

but that doesn't print out the files in the subdirectories (such as `dir/file1.txt`)

Is it possible to print out all files in this directory as well as all subdirectories?

Comment: try `glob.glob('**/*')`, for all files from `pathname` and below, try `glob.glob('pathname/**/*')`, for all directories, try `glob.glob('pathname/**/*/')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a little more difficult using `os.walk`

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for f in filenames:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, f)
```

You can also express this as a generator expression

```
for filename in (os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, fn in os.walk('.') for f in fn):
    # do something with filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

top = 'F:/some/path/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
       print name
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use os.walk.

Example:

```
for (dirname, subs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    print('[' + dirname + ']')
    for fname in files:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
```

See [here for more info](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#files-and-directories)